# Notifications not added to queue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-forge

I've provisioned a Laravel Forge server and configured it to use `redis` for queues via .env:

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=redis
```

My settings for Redis in both `config/queue.php` and `config/database.php` are the defaults found in a new laravel project.

The problem is that when a mail notification is triggered, it is never added to the queue. It never gets to the processing stage.

I've tried using forge's queue interface as well as SSH into the server and running a simple

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

without any parameters. In both cases, no results (using the artisan command confirms no job is added to the queue).

Interestingly, I tried `Beanstalkd`:

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=beanstalkd
```

and suffered the same problem.

As a sanity check, I set the queue driver to sync:

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

and the notification was delivered without issue, so there isn't a problem with my code in the notification class, it's somewhere between calling the notify method and being added to the queue.

The same configuration running locally works fine. I can use

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

and the notifications go through.

Answer (score 0):

After an insane amount of time trying to address this, I discovered it was because the app was in maintenance mode. To be fair, the documentation does state that queued jobs aren't fired in maintenance mode, but unless you knew maintenance mode was the culprit you probably wouldn't be looking in that section.